# Swiping between dynamic UIViews content in IOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

I am new to ios and I am trying to find a way of paging through dynamic content.

An example of what I want to achieve is the BBC News app

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bbc-news/id364147881?mt=8

The user selects the story from a UItableView and is directed to the detail view.

In the detail view, the user is able to swipe back and forth through the stories instead of going back to the table and choosing another story. I don't really want to make a UIView for every story, since it is difficult to determine how many stories there will be.

I would appreciate if someone could point me to an example of this usage.

Comment: You can use pageviewcontroller for a detail view of the story.

Comment: you can place a collectionView inside the detail page and manage rest of the content within.

Comment: As per @Ishika I created a collection view inside of the detail view and it works perfectly, thank you:)

Comment: you are welcome :)